# Show that $W^\infty\cap W^{K-fin}$ is a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie Group, and let $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie Algebra, and let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. Let a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$ module be a vector space $V$ that is acted upon by $K$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ satisfying:

(1) $V\simeq \bigoplus M_K$, where $M_K$ are finite dimensional continuous $K$-modules,

(2) the two actions of $\operatorname{Lie}(K)$ coming from $K$ and the restriction of $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\operatorname{Lie}(K)$ coincide.

(3) For $g\in K$, $a\in\mathfrak{g}$,$v\in V$, $gav=\operatorname{Ad}_g(a)gv$.

**Question**:
Let $W$ be a continuous representation of $G$. Show that $W^\infty\cap W^{K-fin}$ is a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$ module.

---

Result I'm aware of:

$\bigoplus_\pi \operatorname{Hom}(\pi,V)\otimes \pi\simeq V$, where $\pi$ runs over the isomorphism classes of irreducible finite dimensional representations of $K$

I feel like I don't have enough to work with here; how should one proceed?